# Start a activity for each view in viewpager (Solved and Closed)

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello i have a `ViewPager` in a `Fragment` which shows some images. I want to start a new `Activity` for each `View` when the image is clicked. I mean i am showing some pictures in `ViewPager` with circleadapter and i want to open a new pager for each image with zoom option.

Here is my adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Activity _activity;

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutinflater;

    public Adapter(Context context) {
        context = context;
       layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    int[] mResources = {
            R.drawable.img1,
            R.drawable.img2,

    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.page_1, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resim);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);
        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

after adding onclick option

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Class c=null;
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        c=Yenii.class;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        c=Yeni2.class;
                        break;
                    //and……
                }
                Context context = null;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,c);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

but now i am getting this error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Comment: Why are you duplicating [your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039093/can-i-inflate-a-layout-in-pageradapter-when-i-click-on-viewed-picture)? You should instead improve your question and show your research/effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the following change to your code :

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) { //Needs to be final if you want to access it inside an inner class.
        View itemView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.page_1, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resim);
         itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  //launch your activity here.
                  Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullScreenImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("IMAGE_RES_ID", mResources[position]);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);
        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }
```

> And finally in your FullScreenImageActivity OnCreate method :

```
int resourceID = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE_RES_ID", 0);
image.SetImageResource(resourceId); //This is the imageview in the new activity.
```

Comment: oke i got it but still i dont know how can i start different activity for each view.

Comment: you can launch the same activity for every page but just pass the image url with the intent. So when the activity is launched, get the image url from intent and display a bigger image with zoom option there.

Comment: man i am new on androidd app development may you show me how please?

Comment: @murty you might be new but can surely convert an idea/solution to a Java code, right?

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope you understand what you need to do now.

Answer (score 1):

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Class c=null;
        swtich(position){
           case 0:
            c=a.class;
            break;
           case 1:
            c=b.class;
            break;
            //and……
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,c);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

done!

Comment: canot resolve method context dude. and also cannot resolve method startactivity.

Comment: i am getting this error   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference  for this >>  Intent intent = new Intent(context,c);

Comment: @murty so what did Google say about this crash log?

Comment: i did not understand anything actually that's why i'm asking here :)

Comment: i find this line "context = context;",change this.context=context please

Comment: @murty please Google before asking. You won't learn if all you want is spoon-feeding. Roll-up your sleeves and do the hard work by working on your own first.

Comment: @murty You certainly did not figure out this line “context=context"  ,changed to "this.context=contex",and you will resolve

Comment: @Cgx damn i am confused i did not get anything what u said dude